# Time value out of datetime column gets converted to 12 hour format after DataReader.Read

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-2008, datetime, calendar

My app allows users to make meeting appointments. Before the appointment is saved to the database, the user selects a date from a Calendar control. Once a date is selected, the page should get a list of appointments for that day out of the database, and examine the time of day for each recorded appointment. Any timeslots that have already been booked are to be removed from a DropDownList that the user will select a convenient time from.

The problem comes in with my time comparisons. Most of the code below is meant to strip the apart the date/time values to get something I can compare with.

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

    If Not IsPostBack Then

        PopulateTime()
    End If
End Sub

Protected Sub PopulateTime()

    Dim db As New Database

    Dim sql As String = "select apptinterval from centres where centreid = @id"

    Dim args As New List(Of SqlParameter)
    args.Add(New SqlParameter("@id", Session("CentreID")))

    Dim dr As SqlDataReader = db.GetReader(sql, args.ToArray)

    Dim interval As Integer = 0
    If dr.Read Then
        interval = dr("apptinterval")
    End If

    Dim time = TimeSpan.FromHours(8)
    While time < TimeSpan.FromHours(17)
        time += TimeSpan.FromMinutes(interval)

        ddlAppointmentTime.Items.Add(New ListItem(time.ToString, time.ToString))
    End While
End Sub

Protected Sub calAppointmentDate_SelectionChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles calAppointmentDate.SelectionChanged

    Dim seldate As String = Left(calAppointmentDate.SelectedDate, 10)
    Dim dateargs() As String = seldate.ToString.Split("/")
    Dim newdate As String = dateargs(0) & "-" & dateargs(1) & "-" & dateargs(2)

    GetTimes(newdate)
End Sub

Protected Sub GetTimes(ByVal TargetDate As String)

    Dim db As New Database

    Dim args As New List(Of SqlParameter)
    Dim sql As String = "select apptdate from appointments where apptdate between @date1 and @date2 order by apptdate"

    args.Add(New SqlParameter("@date1", TargetDate & " 12:00:00"))
    args.Add(New SqlParameter("@date2", TargetDate & " 23:59:59"))

    Dim dr As SqlDataReader = db.GetReader(sql, args.ToArray)

    If dr.HasRows Then
        dr.Read()
        For i As Integer = 0 To ddlAppointmentTime.Items.Count - 1

            If Left(ddlAppointmentTime.Items(i).Value, 5) = Mid(dr("apptdate"), 12, 5) Then
                ddlAppointmentTime.Items.RemoveAt(i)
            End If

        Next
    End If
    dr.Close()

End Sub
```

If the loop here, the value for `Mid(dr("apptdate"), 12, 5)` is being returned as `01:00`. The actual value in the database says `13:00`.

Can anyone suggest why this conversion is happening? It's causing the comparison to fail, and so, that timeslot is not being removed from the DropDownList.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems it was the `Mid` that did it. The conversion to string involved here changed the value.

I worked around this by removing the `Mid` and changing the sql statement as follows:

```
Dim sql As String = "select left(CONVERT(time, apptdate, 14), 5) as apptdate from appointments"

Dim dr As SqlDataReader = db.GetReader(sql, args.ToArray)

If dr.HasRows Then
    While dr.Read

        For i As Integer = 0 To ddlAppointmentTime.Items.Count - 1

            If Left(ddlAppointmentTime.Items(i).Value, 5) = dr("apptdate") Then
                ddlAppointmentTime.Items.RemoveAt(i)
            End If

        Next
    End While

End If
dr.Close()
```